# Why can't I import candlestick_ohlc from mplfinance

Tags: python, installation, importerror, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

So I have been able to successfully install mplfinance with pip and when I import it alone I receive no error. Though when I do: `from mplfinance import candlestick_ohlc` I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'candlestick_ohlc' from 'mplfinance'` I have checked command prompt again, and it says it has successfully installed mplfinance. Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Can you just `import mplfinance`?

Comment: `from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc`? See https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

Comment: @mkrieger1, I can import mplfinance without an issue, though when I try to get candlestick_ohlc is when I get the error.

Comment: @BigBen, I get the same error

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are importing candlestick? mpf.plot(x, type='candle') will do the trick for you.

Comment: So I found out the reason was because mplfinance has changed the library, so now to use old pacakges, you have to do "from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So from what I understand the Matplotlib for finance has changed so that:

To access the old API with the new mplfinance package installed, change statments

from:

```
from mpl_finance import
```

to:

```
    from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
```

and then it should work fine.

Answer (score 14):

You do not have to import 'candlestick_ohlc' anymore.

'mplfinance.plot()' defaults to ohlc style charts.

These links provide good examples.  The second one uses candlesticks.  You can change that arg.

https://towardsdatascience.com/trading-toolbox-03-ohlc-charts-95b48bb9d748

https://openwritings.net/pg/mplfinance/python-draw-candlestickohlc-using-new-mplfinance

Answer (score -1):

the first thing you have to do is install the library with the command:

pip install mplfinance

after that you can call the resource like:

from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc